# How to express arrays in Isabelle/HOL?

Tags: isabelle

I am trying to express arrays, but don't know exactly how. For example, in the following toy lemma that asserts the sum of a series of numbers equals to certain things:

```
lemma " ∑ {x |x. x ∈ {0..(n::nat)} } = n*(n+1) div 2"
```

, how can I express this for an given array `A[i] = i, i = 0..n`?

I tried to state it unsuccessfully using vectors (`vec`) from
`imports  Complex_Main  "~~/src/HOL/Analysis/Finite_Cartesian_Product"`

as follows:

```
lemma test_array:
  fixes n::nat and A::"(nat,3) vec"
  shows "∑ {A $ x |x. x ∈ {0..(3::nat)} } = 3*4 div 2"
```

First of all, I don't know how to get `vec` to accept a parameter `n` about its size.  Secondly, the conclusion part `"∑ {A $ x |x. x ∈ {0..(3::nat)} }`  has some type errors. Maybe `vec` isn't the right solution. Hence the question here.

In Isabelle, is there any (preferably standard) way to express the array `A[i]` for `i` in a range?

(To clarify, I do not need imperative arrays that can be modified as in programming; I just needed mathematical arrays with a size that is known in advance but not fixed to something like `3`).

Comment: Uh, why don't you just use lists?

Comment: @ManuelEberl I don't use lists because I need indices eventually, e.g. to express arg_min i A[i] s.t. .... Sometimes, the indices may not be in nat. Therefore, I wouldn't want to risk learning how to wrestle with a more basic datastructure such as list or map (while even working with list isn't all that easy for my stage).

Comment: Use a function, not an array. And specify that it is 0 outside of the bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about the concrete applications it is hard to give good advice here.

I believe that the most standard way to do this is to use a function and not an array. If needed, you can express that the values are zero outside of a compact domain. However, sums over infinite objects in Isabelle are always zero.

If you really need something with a length: In the comments you said, you wanted to use `int`, but maybe your indices are positive anyway and you can convert them to `nat`, making it possible to use lists anyway?

Comment: Thanks. I think functions are good mathematically. What I was looking is a representation of n-dim vectors with inner product and potentially matrix multiplication etc. I guess lists or C++-style map can fit the bill eventually. It's just that the implicitity about the indices (and the need to check if the index exists) may get in the way. I have a finite index set that is shared by all vectors involved.

Comment: I was hoping to find an efficient notation with indices.

Comment: Isabelle has matrices https://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL-Matrix_LP/Matrix.html. How about using them?

Comment: Thanks. Matrix seems to be the way. Is there a way to define a specialized type /typedef for column vectors in Isabelle such that the dimension is always `n * 1`? e.g.:   definition `definition vector = {(f::(nat ⇒ 'a::zero)). matrix f and "some_how_2nd_dim = 1"}`?

Comment: IIRC there are two ways to define matrices: One with size constraints in the type (https://www.isa-afp.org/browser_info/current/AFP/Jordan_Normal_Form/Matrix.html) and one without (like done in the entry I linked). In the first case you fight with the types and in the latter with the fact that there is no explicit size.